# Arrays unique element and Mobile apps data structure

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, time-complexity

Recently below questions were asked in an interview

1. You are given an array of integer with all elements repeated twice except one element which occurs only once, you need to find the unique element with O(nlogn)time complexity. Suppose array is {2,47,2,36,3,47,36} the output should be 3 here. I told we can perform merge sort(as it takes(nlogn)) after that we can check next element, but he said it will take O(nlogn)+O(n). I also told we can use HashMap to keep count of elements but again he said no as we have to iterate over hashmap again to get results. After some research, I came to know that using xor operation will give output in O(n). Is there any better solution other than sorting which can give the answer in O(nlogn) time?
2. As we use smartphones we can open many apps at a time. when we look at what all apps are open currently we see a list where the recently opened app is at the front and we can remove or close an app from anywhere on the list. There is some Collection available in java which can perform all these tasks in a very efficient way. I told we can use LinkedList or LinkedHashMap but he was not convinced. What could be the best Collection to use?

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, if the interviewer used Big-O notation and expected a `O(n log n)` solution, there's nothing wrong with your answer. We know that `O(x + y) = O(max(x, y))`. Therefore, although your algorithm is `O(n log n + n)`, it's okay if we just call `O(n log n)`. However, it's possible to find the element that appears once in a sorted array can be achieved in `O(log n)` using binary search. As a hint, exploit odd and even indices while performing search. Also, if the interviewer expected a `O(n log n)` solution, the objection for traversing is absurd. The hash map solution is already `O(n)`, and if there's a problem with this, it's the requirement of extra space. For this reason, the best one is to use XOR as you mentioned. There're still some more `O(n)` solutions but they're not better than the XOR solution.
2. To me, `LinkedList` is proper to use for this task as well. We want to remove from any location and also want to use some stack operations (push, pop, peek). A custom stack can be built from a `LinkedList`.